# Sending data from a one 2 many field of a parent class to a wizard opens from a button click in the parent class

Tags: odoo, one2many

I need to send data in a  one2many field of a form to a a one2many field of a wizard [opens on a button click].. the wizard contains a one2many field of same format.. How to acheive this??

**Parent CLass**

```
class wrhouse(models.Model):

 wproductlist = fields.One2many(comodel_name="productlist1", inverse_name="ppp", string="Product List")

@api.multi

 def Submittopm(self):

result = {
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'res_model': 'submitquantwiz',
    'name': 'Enter Quantity of Stock Needed',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'target': 'new',

}
return result

class productlist1(models.Model)

   _name = "productlist1"

ppp = fields.Char(String="hai")
_rec_name = "productname"
productname = fields.Char(string="Product Name")
reqquantity = fields.Char(string="Required Quantity")
quantav = fields.Char(string="Product Available", onchange="pro_quantity")
maxdate = fields.Date(string="Deadline Date")
```

**Wizard Class**

```
   class wrhousesub(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'submitquantwiz'
No = fields.One2many(comodel_name="id",inverse_name="quant",string="Products")

class wr(models.Model):
_name = "id"
# p = fields.Char(string="ff")
products = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='productlist1',string="Product")
quant = fields.Char(string="Quntities")
```

Comment: Take a look at how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer quickly.

Comment: ഒരു parent model. അതിൽ ഒരു one2many field ഉണ്ട്.. ആ മോഡലിൽ  ഒരു button ഉണ്ട്.. ആ ബട്ടൺ ക്ലിക്ക് ചെയ്യുമ്പോള് ഒരു wizard ഓപ്പൺ ചെയ്തു വരും.. ആ wizardil ഒരു many2one ഫീൽഡ് ഉണ്ട്..  എനിക്ക് വേണ്ടത് ആ ബട്ടൻ ക്ലിക്ക് ചെയ്യുമ്പോൾ parent ക്ലാസ്സിൽ ഉള്ള one2many യുടെ data wizardil ഉള്ള many2one selection  il populate ചെയ്തു വരണം. അത്രേയുള്ളൂ

Comment: code posted in the question bro

Comment: any updates brother?